# Exibir imagem até o gif ser carregado

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou carregando um gif quando o utilizador passa o rato por cima de uma determinada `<div>`. Faço isso usando jQuerry com o seguinte código:

```
$('#vidthumb_' + idDoDiv).attr('src', caminhoParaOGif);
```

o problema é que o gif demora por volta de 1 segundo a carregar, e eu queria mostrar alguma coisa (imagem de loading ou texto) até o gif ser carregado e pronto para ser reproduzido, como devo alterar o meu código?

Comment: Deixei como resposta uma solução para você.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode adicionar um *spinner* feito em CSS após o elemento `<img>`, que será removido após o gif ser carregado pelo `onload`.

Só é preciso colocar a imagem dentro de uma `div` (essa `div` não irá influenciar no *layout*, serve apenas como referência).

**Veja exemplo** (como a transição é muito rápida, deixei comentada a linha que esconde o *spinner* para que se possa vê-lo no exemplo):

```js
caminhoParaOGif = "https://tctechcrunch2011.files.wordpress.com/2015/08/safe_image.gif";

$("#vidthumb_").on("mouseover", function(){
   $(this).after('<span class="loader"></span>');
   $('#vidthumb_')
   .attr('src', caminhoParaOGif)
   .on("load", function(){
//      $(this).next().remove(); // descomente esta linha
   });
});
```

```css
*{
   position: relative;
}

.loader {
    border: 16px solid #f3f3f3; /* cinza */
    border-top: 16px solid #3498db; /* azul */
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -31px 0 0 -31px; /* metade da soma do width + 2x a borda*/
}

@keyframes spin {
    0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="display: inline-block;">
   <img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg" height="200" width="200" id="vidthumb_" />
</div>
```

Comment: Ótimo método, mas vale lembrar que @keyframes não funciona em alguns browsers antigos :D

Comment: Funciona no IE 10+... creio que seja bem satisfatório. :D

Comment: Sim, depende da necessidade e para quem for desenvolver, eu mesmo tenho um projeto em empresa que tive que readaptar o css para o ie7 pois o pessoal só usa ele. Seria ótimo se começassem a acompanhar as atualizações, rs.

Comment: como posso editar/brincar com snippet?

Comment: @ihavenokia Vc pode alterar apenas as dimensões e as cores, alterando o border, o width/height e as cores das bordas.

Comment: @ihavenokia Se quiser colocar outro estilo de spinner, aí vc pode procurar na net algum e substituir, pois a lógica é a mesma.

Answer (score 0):

Como você está atribuindo a imagem via script, a mesma leva um tempo para ser carregada no documento. Uma dica é colocar um gif/imagem que você quer que fique até a sua imagem carregar diretamente no elemento, assim quando o utilizador passar o mouse sobre o elemento, a imagem será apresentada até a nova imagem ser atribuída ao src.
Exemplo:

```js
$('#img').mouseenter(function(){
  $(this).attr('src','http://www.topimagens.com.br/imagens/imagens-mais-novas.jpg');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img id="img" src="https://media2.giphy.com/media/3oEjI6SIIHBdRxXI40/giphy.gif"/>
```

Comment: mas neste caso acontece exatamente o problema que eu tenho, se **imagens-mais-novas.jpg** for um gif e demorar a carregar vai dar a sensaçao que é uma mera imagem e o utilizador poderá tirar o rato em cima da div pois ela fica algum tempo sem 'se mexer'.